# 1-to-1 correspondence between twin primes and $n^2-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, prime-numbers

I am trying to establish the one-to-one correspondence of twin primes to integers $n$ where $n^2-1$ has 4 divisors.  It is clear to me that this is the case, since 
$$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$$
where the RHS would represent the twin primes.  I think I can set my bijection up using the function
$$f(n-1,n+1)=(n-1)(n+1)$$
HOwever, I'm having difficulties starting this argument off.  I need to show injectivity and surjectivity.  Thus, 
$$f(n_1-1,n_1+1)=f(n_2-1,n_2+1)$$
$$(n_1-1)(n_1+1)=(n_2-1)(n_2+1)$$
$$n_1^2-1=n_2^2-1$$
$$n_1^2=n_2^2$$
$$\sqrt{n_1^2}=\sqrt{n_2^2}$$
$$n_1=n_2$$
I took a liberty here since I'm pretty sure since dealing with twin primes and primes in general the assumption would be we are working in the positive integer realm (or at least non-negative)
Now for surjectivity, I take an integer from the set of numbers of the form $n^2-1$  Then
$$n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)=(6k-1)(6k+1)=f(6k-1,6k+1).$$
I chose $6k-1, 6k+1$ since a previous exercise had me show there twin primes come in the form.  To finalize the surjection, I have to tie in the fact that there are twin primes (3,5) that do not fall in this form.  So how do I complete my argument, if it is correct to begin with?

Comment: What exactly are the domain and codomain of your function $f$?  Without this information it does not make sense to ask whether it is a bijection or not.

Comment: @David Looks like the domain consists of twin-prime pairs, and the codomain consists of integers of the form $n^2 - 1$ that have exactly four factors.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven To show surjectivity, just take an arbitrary integer of the form $n^2 - 1$ with exactly four factors, and show that $n - 1$ and $n + 1$ must be prime.

Comment: Domain is the set of twin primes and the range is the set of all integers of the form $n^2-1$ having 4 divisors.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven You should call that the codomain. You can call it the "range" only after you've shown that the mapping is surjective :)

Comment: Okay, thanks Vinay.  So how to show that n+1 and n-1 are prime for arbitrary integers of the above form is my task... Hmmmm

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven It should be pretty easy to argue. We know that $1$, $(n - 1)$, $(n + 1)$, and $n^2 - 1$ are distinct factors of $n^2 - 1$. If these are the only factors, $n - 1$ and $n + 1$ must be $\ldots$?

Comment: Oh yeah. Staring me in the face.  Clearly prime.  And that will cover the exception twins of 3 & 5 as well.  Thanks! You could make that an answer and I'd be happy to upvote!

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven You should answer with the neatly written, complete proof, and *I*'d be happy to upvote :P

Comment: I will do so in the morning as I am I'm bed now.  I take it that my injectivity portion is valid then?

Comment: Yes, that's fine as it is.

Comment: I posted a proof anyway (with a slightly different proof of injectivity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{align}\text{Let}\ T & = \{ (p, q) \mid p, q \in \mathbb{P},\ q - p = 2 \}\\
V & = \{n^2 - 1 \mid n \in \mathbb{N},\ \text{d}(n^2-1) = 4\}
\end{align}$

**Theorem [Eleven-Eleven]**
$T \cong V$

*Proof*
Let $f:T \to V$, $(p, q) \mapsto pq$.

1. $f(p_1, q_1) = f(p_2, q_2) \Rightarrow\\
   p_1q_1  = p_2q_2 \Rightarrow\\
   p_1 = p_2,\ q_1 = q_2\ [\text{unique prime factorization of $p_1q_1 = p_2q_2$, with $p_1 < q_1$, $p_2 < q_2$}]$
   $\therefore$ $f$ is an injection.
2. Let $n^2 - 1 \in V$.
   $1$, $n - 1$, $n + 1$, $n^2 - 1$ are distinct factors of $n^2 - 1$, and $d(n^2 - 1) = 4$ $\Rightarrow$
   $(n - 1), (n + 1) \in \mathbb{P} \Rightarrow$
   $(n - 1, n + 1) \in T,\ f(n - 1, n + 1) = n^2 - 1$
   $\therefore$ $f$ is a surjection.

1, 2 $\Rightarrow$ $f$ is a bijection.
$\therefore T \cong V$